# How to detect and react to route changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-apollo

I have a multi page form which depends on a few pieces of data.

```
const formQueryWrapper = ({...routerProps}) => {
  return (
    <Query> <MultiPageForm {queryProps}/> </Query>
  )
}

export default withRouter(formQueryWrapper)
```

And when the form is successfully completed, I can reliably pass some state `formCompleted: true` with my Redirect and do the thing I wanted to do.

But the issue I'm facing right now is; I also want to react if the form wasn't completed successfully.

I tried to do a few checks in `ComponentWillUnmount()` but the entire page keeps re-rendering whenever the sidebar navigation animation happens.

I tried to do the `history.listen((location, action) => {...})` seems viable, but a little messy *probably*

Is there another way I should tackle this problem without history?
Is there something I'm missing with the react-router listen?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use a state management, if you want logic shared in other pages. Try using Redux.